# XSL transformation - how to look for linking node

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am new to XSL transformation. I am transforming the following XML to another XML format:

```
<root>

 <header>
   <section id="a1">
     <color>red</color>
   </section>

   <section id="a2">
     <color>blue</color>
   </section>

 </header>

 <body>
   This is the sample text <reference link="a1">with color red</reference> 
   and <reference link="a2">with color blue</reference>
 </body> 

</root>
```

The section id (in header) is linked to the reference link (in body). I have to look for color 'blue' in `<color>` node. If it is available, then i have to delete the parent `<section>` node. Along with that, the 'id' of that section is "a2". The corresponding reference link in body has to be deleted. The result:

```
<root>

 <header>
   <section id="a1">
     <color>red</color>
   </section>

 </header>

 <body>
   This is the sample text <reference link="a1">with color red</reference> 
   and with color blue
 </body> 

</root>
```

Can anyone please give some hints on how to start?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or are you limited to 1.0? Do you want to hard-code "blue" as the target or does it need to be passed in as a parameter?

Comment: The server has Java 1.5. Does it support XSLT 2.0? Can you please tell how to check the version? I want to hard-code 'blue'.

Comment: @Mahesh: I believe that JDK 1.5 shipped with a version of Xalan that implements XSLT 1.0, but you could easily switch to Saxon and run XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the `@id` of the section that has `blue` and then strip that `section` and "unwrap" the `reference`.

Here are 2 examples. One in XSLT 1.0 and one in XSLT 2.0.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="toStrip" select="'blue'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="stripRef" select="//section[color=$toStrip]/@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="header">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::section[@id=$stripRef])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="reference">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@link=$stripRef">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="toStrip" select="'blue'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="stripRef" select="//section[color=$toStrip]/@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[@id=$stripRef]"/>

    <xsl:template match="reference[@link=$stripRef]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS**

Here is one way you can handle multiple IDs. Since the `toStrip` param can't be a sequence, we need to add a character to delimit the values. In this example I used `|`. This is so the `contains()` won't be true when comparing something like `a1` to `a10`.

Also, XSLT 1.0 will only return the first `@id` in the `stripRef` variable select. To get all the IDs, I added an `xsl:for-each`. You could also do this with `xsl:apply-templates` by using a mode.

Here's the updated XSLT:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="toStrip" select="'|blue|orange|'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="stripRef">
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="//section[color[contains($toStrip,concat('|',.,'|'))]]/@id">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'|')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="header">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::section[contains($stripRef,concat('|',@id,'|'))])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="reference">
        <xsl:message>contains(<xsl:value-of select="$stripRef"/>,<xsl:value-of select="concat('|',@link,'|')"/>)</xsl:message>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($stripRef,concat('|',@link,'|'))">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To do this same thing in XSLT 2.0, you would just need to change the `toStrip` param to a sequence:

```
<xsl:param name="toStrip" select="('blue','orange')"/>
```

Comment: You may find that the "2.0" version actually works in your existing Xalan-based setup - the XSLT 1.0 spec forbids the use of variable references in match patterns but I've found Xalan does in fact allow this, at least in some versions.

Comment: @Daniel Haley: Thank you very much for the help. I have another query. Is there a way to get multiple ids in StripRef? For example, if i want to exclude blue and orange.

Comment: @Mahesh - Yes that is possible. It's very easy in 2.0. Are you using 2.0 or 1.0?

Comment: @Daniel Haley: I am using 1.0

Comment: @Mahesh - I've added examples for both 1.0 and 2.0. As you can see, 2.0 is much simpler.

Comment: @DanielHaley: Thank you once again, Daniel. I appreciate it.